# Tell when keyboard with "adjustNothing" opens

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

In my app I am using the adjustNothing flag to my keyboard. That it a requirement..
Please don't advice me to change it to "resize or pan" :)

My question is if there is any way of knowing when the keyboard opens and closes in this state?

I tried "onGlobalLayout" and "onConfigurationChanged" without any luck.
Since the keyboard is not "doing" anything to the app I don't seam to find  any way the catch this event..
Please help!

Comment: Did you find a solution eventually ? @roiberg

Comment: Yes I did!
Look at the answer I added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes! It's not nice as iOS where you get the height and animation but at least you know that it opens:

```
ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(findViewById(android.R.id.content), new OnApplyWindowInsetsListener() {
                @Override
                public WindowInsetsCompat onApplyWindowInsets(View v, WindowInsetsCompat insets) {
}
```

This tells you whenever any kind of change happens. It's easy knowing that the keyboard is the reason for that change and act accordingly.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. The callback is invoked only once when creating an activity. Tested on API 22.

Comment: `if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21)`